# Gremlin: Is there a way to find the character based on the index of a string?

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I have vertex "office" and property "name" on OrientDB. I want to find the offices, by name, where the name does not have a "-" as the third character of the string. I imagine this would require some java code within the gremlin query.This is my best attempt, but it is resulting in office names that do in fact have a "-" as their third character.

`g.V().hasLabel('office')
.where(values('name').map{it.get().charAt(2)}.is(neq('-')))
.project('Office Name')
.by(values('name'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Gremlin doesn't support String operations (like `split`, `charAt`, etc.), your only chance is a lambda. Seems like you figured that out already, but your solution looks too overcomplicated to me. You can use something much simpler, like:

```
g.V().hasLabel('office').
  has('name', filter {it.get()[2] != '-'}).
  project('Office Name').
    by('name')
```

However, note, that this filter will throw an exception if the office namer has less than 3 characters. Thus, you should better check that the `String` is long enough:

```
g.V().hasLabel('office').
  has('name', filter {it.get().length() > 2 && it.get()[2] != '-'}).
  project('Office Name').
    by('name')
```

...or use RegEx pattern matching (which is pretty nice and easy in Groovy):

```
g.V().hasLabel('office').
  has('name', filter {it.get() ==~ /.{2}-.*/}).
  project('Office Name').
    by('name')
```

The main reason why your traversal didn't work though, is that `charAt` returns a `Character` which is then compared to the `String` `-`, hence every office name will pass the `neq` filter.

Comment: Just stopping by to add a comment that starting with Apache TinkerPop version 3.6.0 the language now includes a `TextP.regex` predicate. Hopefully string manipulation functions will follow in a future update.